# How to lock IO shared by fork in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, fork

How can we lock an IO that has been shared by multiple ruby process?

Consider this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
# vim: ts=2 sw=2 et
if ARGV.length != 2
  $stderr.puts "Usage: test-io-fork.rb num_child num_iteration"
  exit 1
end
CHILD = ARGV[0].to_i
ITERATION = ARGV[1].to_i

def now
  t = Time.now
  "#{t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}.#{t.usec}"
end

MAP = %w(nol satu dua tiga empat lima enam tujuh delapan sembilan)

IO.popen('-', 'w') {|pipe|
  unless pipe
    # Logger child
    File.open('test-io-fork.log', 'w') {|log|
      log.puts "#{now} Program start"
      $stdin.each {|line|
        log.puts "#{now} #{line}"
      }
      log.puts "#{now} Program end"
    }
    exit!
  end
  pipe.sync = true
  pipe.puts "Before fork"
  CHILD.times {|c|
    fork {
      pid = Process.pid
      srand
      ITERATION.times {|i|
        n = rand(9)
        sleep(n / 100000.0)
        pipe.puts "##{c}:#{i} #{MAP[n]} => #{n}, #{n} => #{MAP[n]} ##{c}:#{i}"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And try it like this:

```
./test-io-fork.rb 200 50
```

Like expected, the test-io-fork.log files would contains sign of IO race condition.

What I want to achieve is to make a TCP server for custom GPS protocol that will save the GPS points to database. Because this server would handle 1000 concurrent clients, I would like to restrict database connection to only one child instead opening 1000 database connection simultaneously. This server would run on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It may be bad form to update after the answer was accepted, but the original is a bit misleading.  Whether or not ruby makes a separate `write(2)` call for the automatically-appended newline is dependent upon the buffering state of the output IO object.

`$stdout` (when connected to a tty) is generally line-buffered, so the effect of a `puts()` -- given reasonably sized string -- with implicitly added newline is a single call to `write(2)`.  Not so, however, with `IO.pipe` and `$stderr`, as the OP discovered.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Change your chief `pipe.puts()` argument to be a *newline terminated* string:

```
pipe.puts "##{c} ... #{i}\n"  # <-- note the newline
```

Why?  You set `pipe.sync` hoping that the pipe writes would be atomic and non-interleaved, since they are (presumably) less than [`PIPE_BUF`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/write.html) bytes.  But it didn't work, because ruby's pipe `puts()` implementation *makes a separate call to write(2) to append the trailing newline,* and that's why your writes are sometimes interleaved where you expected a newline.

Here's a corroborating excerpt from a fork-following strace of your script:

```
$ strace -s 2048 -fe trace=write ./so-1326067.rb
....
4574  write(4, "#0:12 tiga => 3, 3 => tiga #0:12", 32) = 32
4574  write(4, "\n", 1)
....
```

But putting in your own newline solves the problem, making sure that your entire record is transmitted in one syscall:

```
....
5190  write(4, "#194:41 tujuh => 7, 7 => tujuh #194:41\n", 39 <unfinished ...>
5179  write(4, "#183:38 enam => 6, 6 => enam #183:38\n", 37 <unfinished ...>
....
```

If for some reason that cannot work for you, you'll have to coordinate an interprocess mutex (like `File.flock()`).